# Difference between time() and stime()

Tags: c, time, posix

What is the difference in function between `time()` from the standard library and `stime()` from the POSIX extension?

If `stime()` sets *system* time, then what time does `time()` set?

Comment: `man time` `man stime` What could be simpler?

Comment: ?? `time()` does not change the time of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX's `stime()` always uses the midnight of January first 1970 as the "epoch begin" time and is **only** available to a superuser whereas standard library's `time()` uses system-defined (usually either 1900 or 1970) epoch and has no access restrictions.

Also the `time()` does not *set* a time, it only reads it back from the system, which is the reason it is not restricted to superuser or similar access.